# Mapbox Directions API returns straight line

Tags: mapbox

For about a week now the Directions Api doesn't always return a path that follows the streets, but is a direct line of flight. This happens only for short routes. I manage to produce this here for example with the following start and end coordinates:

https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/

from: -79.45188300000001,43.65414199999998
to: -79.45447200000001,43.655884000000015

The same behaviour happens in my Unity app that uses Mapbox directions. Interestingly, on https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/directions/ the path is actually correct. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When I enter the coordinates on https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/directions/, it reverse geocodes them to addresses ("2235a Dundas Street West, Toronto, Ontario M6R 3A9, Canada", "1575 Bloor Street West, Toronto, Ontario M6P 1A6, Canada").That's probably the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the request parameter `overview=full`?

This was a known issue, that has been resolved by Mapbox. A fix has been deployed for the issue of over-simplifying route overview geometry when `overview=simplified` (which is the default) used.